# Numpy test() finished with errors

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy

on ubuntu 12.04 x32 I have installed python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.1 via `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`. I run the `test()` from numpy via `numpy.test()` and I get:

> ### FAIL: test_pareto (test_random.TestRandomDist)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/random/tests/test_random.py", line 313, in test_pareto
>       np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(actual, desired, decimal=15)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 800, in assert_array_almost_equal
>       header=('Arrays are not almost equal to %d decimals' % decimal))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 636, in assert_array_compare
>       raise AssertionError(msg)
>   AssertionError: 
>   Arrays are not almost equal to 15 decimals
>
> (mismatch 16.6666666667%)
>    x: array([[  2.46852460e+03,   1.41286881e+03],
>          [  5.28287797e+07,   6.57720981e+07],
>          [  1.40840323e+02,   1.98390255e+05]])
>    y: array([[  2.46852460e+03,   1.41286881e+03],
>          [  5.28287797e+07,   6.57720981e+07],
>          [  1.40840323e+02,   1.98390255e+05]])
>
> ---
>
> Ran 3169 tests in 17.483s
>
> FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=3, SKIP=4, failures=1)

What should I do? did I miss a dependency or so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notes for the future me, when trying to redo the stuff:

1. there are some prerequisites for working with `numpy`/`scipy`: `g++` `gfortran` `blas` `atlas` `lapack`.
2. it seems to be better -- and time consuming -- to compile the numpy/scipy sources. pip install does this.

The commands were:

> sudo apt-get install g++ gfortran liblapack-dev libopenblas-dev python-dev python-pip
>
> sudo pip install nose
>
> sudo pip install numpy
>
> python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"

For the scipy library the following worked:

> sudo pip install scipy
>
> python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"