# Build developer's version of scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am new and trying to contribute to `scipy` development. I forked scipy in my github and tried to build it based on [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/hacking.html#recommended-development-setup). However, while trying to import `scipy` in Python, I get the following error:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I also have tried installing all the necessary pre-requirements as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220842/numpy-test-finished-with-errors). I know I can do `pip install scipy`, but that's not the point of building the developer version of scipy, I guess. Can someone help?

Comment: `trying to contribute to scipy` +1

Comment: @MaxU: Indeed, it is motivating to work on open source projects and contribute to the society. Moreover, the encouragement in the community is very welcoming!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5893 which suggest to add scipy in your `PYTHONPATH`: `export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/path/to/scipy/:$PYTHONPATH"`

More info on how to do this per different system from scipy documentation ([FAQ section](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/hacking.html#faq)):

> On Linux and OSX, you can run the command:
>
> ```
> $ export PYTHONPATH=$PWD
> ```
>
> and on Windows
>
> ```
> $ set PYTHONPATH=/path/to/scipy
> ```

Another workaround is also suggested in the before-mentioned issue, which is to open the scipy build as a PyCharm project and create a virtual environment within the IDE to use for your coding!

Good luck :)